# How can I send the multiple checkbox value in Ajax and show in different div?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a jsp page. There are some checkbox. I want get the values of checkboxes and attach them in data: of ajax and by calling ajax ,a div will be open and the values of checkbox will be looked like this:

> fruits: Lichi,Mango

my JSP page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring Jquery Ajax Demo</title>
<style>
Table.GridOne {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    background: lightyellow;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
    width:35%;
}
Table.GridOne Td {  
    padding:2px;
    border: 1px solid #ff9900;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function madeAjaxCall(){

     var country = $('#country').val();
     var gender = $('input:radio[name=sex]:checked').val();
     var val = [];
     var fruit = new Array();
     $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
       val[i] = $(this).val();
       fruit.push(val[i]);
       alert(val[i]);
     });

     var objj = {
             fruits: fruit,

         };
     alert(objj);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/SpringAjaxQuery/employee",
        cache: false,       

        data:'firstName=' + $("#firstName").val() + "&lastName=" + $("#lastName").val() + "&email=" + $("#email").val() + "&gender=" + gender + "&country=" + country +  "&fruits=" +JSON.stringify(objj),
        success: function(response){
            $('#result').html("");
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#result').html("First Name:- " + obj.firstName +"</br>Last Name:- " + obj.lastName  + "</br>Email:- " + obj.email + "</br>Gender:- " + obj.gender + "</br>Country:- " + obj.country + "</br>fruit:- " 
                    + obj.fruits);
            document.forms["employeeForm"].reset();

        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
    });

}
</script>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <form name="employeeForm" method="post">    
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="GridOne">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="removeLater" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="removeLater" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="removeLater" name="email" id="email" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><select id="country" class="removeLater">
                       <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
                       <option value="China">China</option>
                       <option value="United State">United State</option>
                       <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                       <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="genderradio" class="removeLater">Gender</td>
                <td>        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
                            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
                            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Other</input>
                                                                                          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Favourite Fruit</td>
                <td><input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox1" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox2" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Lichi" />Lichi
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox3" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Mango" />Mango
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox4" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Banana" />Banana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall();"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
     <h1>Spring Framework Jquery Ajax</h1>
    <div id="result" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

:[image: How the output is like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the value of fruits input is not well received try to change your snippet code that get the checkbox values to this one

```
var checkboxValues = [];
$('input.removeLater:checked').map(function() {
            checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

now when you do a `console.log(checkboxValues)` it will appears the data that was checked.

```js
$("input.test").click(function(){
  getCheckboxVal();
});

function getCheckboxVal(){
var checkboxValues = [];
$('input.removeLater:checked').map(function() {
            checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(checkboxValues);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox1" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox2" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Lichi" />Lichi
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox3" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Mango" />Mango
                    <input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox4" class="removeLater" type="checkbox" value="Banana" />Banana

<input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" class="test" >
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487013/after-submit-display-checkbox-values-in-div

Comment: what to do to get the values in div. after clicking applying button.for the above link