# After submit display checkbox values in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am tried to display the checkbox values after submit or apply button. Can anybody help me with this. I want values to be displayed after submit button. particular column values display after particular column apply button is clicked.  all the values should be in single div. This functionality is for filter.

**(This will be done in back-end)** after apply button the values on second column will change according to the checked values of first column. and so on.

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#results')
            .append('<li class="">' + $this.val() + '  <a href="#" class="item" data-cb="' + $this.data('ref') + '"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/504-5042965_close-wrong-cross-black-png-transparent-png.png"></a> </li>');
    } else {
        removeCheckedResult($('.item[data-cb=' + $this.data('ref') + ']'));
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removeCheckedResult($(this));
});

function removeCheckedResult($child) {
    $child.parent().remove();
    $('input[class=mainlist][data-ref=' + $child.data('cb') + ']').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.container .hidden-menu{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .hidden-menu li{
  padding:10px 15px;
}
.container .hidden-menu li img{
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test2" data-ref="2">test2<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test3" data-ref="3">test3<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test4" data-ref="4">test4<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test5" data-ref="5">test5<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="6">test6<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test7" data-ref="7">test7<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test8" data-ref="8">test8<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test9" data-ref="9">test9<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test10" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test11" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test13" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test14" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test15" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="row hidden-menu clearfix" id="results">
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help:

```js
$(function() {
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    /*var $this = $(this);

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#results')
            .append('<li class="">' + $this.val() + '  <a href="#" class="item" data-cb="' + $this.data('ref') + '"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/504-5042965_close-wrong-cross-black-png-transparent-png.png"></a> </li>');
            
            
            
    } else {
        removeCheckedResult($('.item[data-cb=' + $this.data('ref') + ']'));
    }*/
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removeCheckedResult($(this));
});

function removeCheckedResult($child) {
    $child.parent().remove();
    $('input[class=mainlist][data-ref=' + $child.data('cb') + ']').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
}
   
  $("button").on("click", function(e){
  var arr =[];
     var arr1 =[];
     $("#results").html('');
   e.preventDefault();
   var count =  document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")
   for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    arr.push(count[i].value);
    arr1.push(count[i].getAttribute("data-ref"));
  }
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    
     $("#results").append(`<li>`+arr[j]+`<a href="#" class="item" data-cb="` + arr1[j] + `"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/504-5042965_close-wrong-cross-black-png-transparent-png.png"></a></li>`)
    }
   
   /*$(this).next("span").text(arr);*/

  })
})
```

```css
.container .hidden-menu{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .hidden-menu li{
  padding:10px 15px;
}
.container .hidden-menu li img{
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test22" data-ref="2">test2<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test33" data-ref="3">test3<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test44" data-ref="4">test4<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test55" data-ref="5">test5<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="6">test6<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test7" data-ref="7">test7<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test8" data-ref="8">test8<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test9" data-ref="9">test9<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test10" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test11" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test13" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test14" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test15" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="row hidden-menu clearfix" id="results">
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want the values inside "ul" section only. Same functionality it should display inside " ul" section

Comment: I want all checkbox values in div. for example when you click on first apply, the checked values of first column should come inside "ul" and when you click on second apply, The checked values of second column should come in "ul"  next to first column values continuously and so on.. for 3rd and 4th.. The respected column values should come when respected apply button is clicked.

Comment: see this image in link. It will explain the design

Comment: I want only checkbox values in ul after apply button

Comment: the reference for this example is this https://www.edureka.co/all-courses       filter section.  (other filters option)

Comment: so one apply button in fine?

Comment: NO its a reference.. In every column apply button will be there.

Comment: See the image link.

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you. for your help. it helped me a lot. and i learnt how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

See the Snippet Below :-

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#results')
            .append('<li class="">' + $this.val() + '  <a href="#" class="item" data-cb="' + $this.data('ref') + '"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/504-5042965_close-wrong-cross-black-png-transparent-png.png"></a> </li>');
    } else {
        removeCheckedResult($('.item[data-cb=' + $this.data('ref') + ']'));
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removeCheckedResult($(this));
});

function removeCheckedResult($child) {
    $child.parent().remove();
    $('input[class=mainlist][data-ref=' + $child.data('cb') + ']').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#results").addClass("shows");
  });
});
```

```css
.container .hidden-menu{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .hidden-menu li{
  padding:10px 15px;
}
.container .hidden-menu li img{
  width:10px;
}
#results{display:none;}
ul#results.shows {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test2" data-ref="2">test2<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test3" data-ref="3">test3<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test4" data-ref="4">test4<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test5" data-ref="5">test5<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="6">test6<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test7" data-ref="7">test7<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test8" data-ref="8">test8<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test9" data-ref="9">test9<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test10" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test11" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test13" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test14" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test15" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="row hidden-menu clearfix" id="results">
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The Values should come after clicking particular apply button.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#results')
            .append('<li class="">' + $this.val() + '  <a href="#" class="item" data-cb="' + $this.data('ref') + '"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/504-5042965_close-wrong-cross-black-png-transparent-png.png"></a> </li>');
    } else {
        removeCheckedResult($('.item[data-cb=' + $this.data('ref') + ']'));
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removeCheckedResult($(this));
});

function removeCheckedResult($child) {
    $child.parent().remove();
    $('input[class=mainlist][data-ref=' + $child.data('cb') + ']').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
}
 $("button").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var count =  $(this).parent().find("input:checked").length
 $(this).next("span").text(count)

})
```

```css
.container .hidden-menu{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .hidden-menu li{
  padding:10px 15px;
}
.container .hidden-menu li img{
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test2" data-ref="2">test2<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test3" data-ref="3">test3<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test4" data-ref="4">test4<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test5" data-ref="5">test5<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="6">test6<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test7" data-ref="7">test7<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test8" data-ref="8">test8<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test9" data-ref="9">test9<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test10" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test11" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test13" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test14" data-ref="10">test10<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test15" data-ref="11">test11<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test12" data-ref="12">test12<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="mainlist" value="test6" data-ref="13">test13<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <button>Apply</button><span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="row hidden-menu clearfix" id="results">
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```